# How can I prevent connection leaks to Cassandra (if that is what is happening here)?

Tags: sockets, cassandra

My web application that fetches data from Cassandra is reporting a warning:

> Network.Socket.socket: resource exhausted (Too many open files)

and in fact the web application is no longer servicing requests. Trying out `lsof`, I see about 7,000 of these (`FarmDataS` is the application in question):

```
FarmDataS 28642                            nixos  628u     IPv4            7629405       0t0        TCP localhost:50566->localhost:9042 (ESTABLISHED)
FarmDataS 28642                            nixos  629u     IPv4            7620920       0t0        TCP localhost:45194->localhost:9042 (ESTABLISHED)
FarmDataS 28642                            nixos  630u     IPv4            7623877       0t0        TCP localhost:46636->localhost:9042 (ESTABLISHED)
FarmDataS 28642                            nixos  631u     IPv4            7630014       0t0        TCP localhost:50576->localhost:9042 (ESTABLISHED)
FarmDataS 28642                            nixos  632u     IPv4            7620925       0t0        TCP localhost:45208->localhost:9042 (ESTABLISHED)
FarmDataS 28642                            nixos  633u     IPv4            7627004       0t0        TCP localhost:48962->localhost:9042 (ESTABLISHED)
FarmDataS 28642                            nixos  634u     IPv4            7623892       0t0        TCP localhost:46650->localhost:9042 (ESTABLISHED)
FarmDataS 28642                            nixos  635u     IPv4            7620930       0t0        TCP localhost:45222->localhost:9042 (ESTABLISHED)
FarmDataS 28642                            nixos  636u     IPv4            7629433       0t0        TCP localhost:50584->localhost:9042 (ESTABLISHED)
FarmDataS 28642                            nixos  637u     IPv4            7632021       0t0        TCP localhost:51616->localhost:9042 (ESTABLISHED)
FarmDataS 28642                            nixos  638u     IPv4            7620935       0t0        TCP localhost:45236->localhost:9042 (ESTABLISHED)
FarmDataS 28642                            nixos  639u     IPv4            7623911       0t0        TCP localhost:46664->localhost:9042 (ESTABLISHED)
FarmDataS 28642                            nixos  640u     IPv4            7625707       0t0        TCP localhost:48976->localhost:9042 (ESTABLISHED)
FarmDataS 28642                            nixos  641u     IPv4            7621926       0t0        TCP localhost:45250->localhost:9042 (ESTABLISHED)
FarmDataS 28642                            nixos  642u     IPv4            7632589       0t0        TCP localhost:52138->localhost:9042 (ESTABLISHED)
FarmDataS 28642                            nixos  643u     IPv4            7623930       0t0        TCP localhost:46678->localhost:9042 (ESTABLISHED)
FarmDataS 28642                            nixos  644u     IPv4            7621945       0t0        TCP localhost:45264->localhost:9042 (ESTABLISHED)
FarmDataS 28642                            nixos  645u     IPv4            7630028       0t0        TCP localhost:50600->localhost:9042 (ESTABLISHED)
FarmDataS 28642                            nixos  646u     IPv4            7625726       0t0        TCP localhost:48990->localhost:9042 (ESTABLISHED)
FarmDataS 28642                            nixos  647u     IPv4            7621964       0t0        TCP localhost:45278->localhost:9042 (ESTABLISHED)
FarmDataS 28642                            nixos  648u     IPv4            7623948       0t0        TCP localhost:46692->localhost:9042 (ESTABLISHED)
FarmDataS 28642                            nixos  649u     IPv4            7627011       0t0        TCP localhost:48998->localhost:9042 (ESTABLISHED)
FarmDataS 28642                            nixos  650u     IPv4            7621983       0t0        TCP localhost:45292->localhost:9042 (ESTABLISHED)
FarmDataS 28642                            nixos  651u     IPv4            7629447       0t0        TCP localhost:50616->localhost:9042 (ESTABLISHED)
FarmDataS 28642                            nixos  652u     IPv4            7623967       0t0        TCP localhost:46706->localhost:9042 (ESTABLISHED)
FarmDataS 28642                            nixos  653u     IPv4            7622000       0t0        TCP localhost:45306->localhost:9042 (ESTABLISHED)
FarmDataS 28642                            nixos  654u     IPv4            7632024       0t0        TCP localhost:51622->localhost:9042 (ESTABLISHED)
FarmDataS 28642                            nixos  655u     IPv4            7630061       0t0        TCP localhost:50626->localhost:9042 (ESTABLISHED)
FarmDataS 28642                            nixos  656u     IPv4            7622019       0t0        TCP localhost:45320->localhost:9042 (ESTABLISHED)
FarmDataS 28642                            nixos  657u     IPv4            7623986       0t0        TCP localhost:46720->localhost:9042 (ESTABLISHED)
FarmDataS 28642                            nixos  658u     IPv4            7632058       0t0        TCP localhost:51642->localhost:9042 (ESTABLISHED)
FarmDataS 28642                            nixos  659u     IPv4            7620953       0t0        TCP localhost:45334->localhost:9042 (ESTABLISHED)
```

I imagine this is a symptom of a connection being leaked somewhere, or is there some other culprit? I'm surprised the idle connections aren't cleaned up, but maybe this is a configuration setting I could change in Cassandra?

Comment: Usually we get this kind of errors on our test-servers, which are way to small. Have you observed your server loads?

Comment: can you check the ulimit on your node, check https://docs.datastax.com/en/archived/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/install/installRecommendSettings.html#reference_ds_sxl_gf3_2k__user-resource-limits

Comment: whats your client pooling configuration? You can limit your app to 1 connection per node.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I'm trying ulimit config changes first as I also found that document while investigating the problem - will see if that helps once I fix some unrelated issues that occurred.

Comment: @vermaji do those limits only need to be applied to the cassandra server user, or also the cassandra client? because my issue is with the client as shown in the output above (`FarmDataS` is run as a different user than the cassandra process`).

Comment: OK, I've confirmed it was a ClientState leak in my application code causing the issue, so just being more careful with resource management (e.g. using bracketing) helped with that.